# Run multiple ODBC connection using paralell pooling in matlab

Tags: matlab, parallel-processing, odbc

I need to retrieve 2 times very similar data from a database and I would like to run the 2 query in parallel using parallel pooling in matlab. Here is my code:

```
parpool('local',12)

parfor i=1:2

%Set preferences with setdbprefs.
setdbprefs('DataReturnFormat', 'cellarray');
setdbprefs('NullNumberRead', 'NaN');
setdbprefs('NullStringRead', 'null');

    if i == 1  
        %Make connection to database.  
        %Using ODBC driver.
        conn1 = database('qad', 'ngc', 'ngc');

        %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
        %Read CLOSING PRICE DATA%%
        %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
        curs1 = exec(conn1, ['SELECT    Russell1000_Prices_Close.date_'...
            ' , Russell1000_Prices_Close.RUSSELL1000_mcapW'...
            ' , Russell1000_Prices_Close.ID'...
            ' , Russell1000_Prices_Close.Close_'...
            ' FROM  qai.dbo.Russell1000_Prices_Close']);

        curs1 = fetch(curs1);
        close(curs1);

        %Assign data to output variable
        temp = curs1.Data;
        pricesPivot = pivottable(temp, [1,2], 3, 4, @sum);
        dates_ = datetime(pricesPivot(2:end,1),'inputFormat','yyyy-MM-dd');
        pricesClose_ = cell2mat(pricesPivot(2:end,3:end));
        pricesMarketmcapW_ = cell2mat(pricesPivot(2:end,2));
        compIDs_ = pricesPivot(1,3:end);

        %Close database connection.
        close(conn1);
    else
        %Make connection to database.  
        %Using ODBC driver.
        conn2 = database('qad', 'ngc', 'ngc');

        %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
        %Read OPENING PRICE DATA%%
        %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
        curs2 = exec(conn2, ['SELECT    Russell1000_Prices_Open.date_'...
            ' , Russell1000_Prices_Open.RUSSELL1000_mcapW'...
            ' , Russell1000_Prices_Open.ID'...
            ' , Russell1000_Prices_Open.Open_'...
            ' FROM  qai.dbo.Russell1000_Prices_Open']);

        curs2 = fetch(curs2);
        close(curs2);

        %Assign data to output variable
        temp = curs2.Data;
        pricesPivot = pivottable(temp, [1,2], 3, 4, @sum);
        dates1_ = datetime(pricesPivot(2:end,1),'inputFormat','yyyy-MM-dd');
        pricesOpen_ = cell2mat(pricesPivot(2:end,3:end));
        compIDs_ = pricesPivot(1,3:end);

        %Close database connection.
        close(conn2);
    end
end
```

First am I using parallel pooling properly in order to speed up the query rather than doing it iteratively? And second, is that the best way or is there any other options to run those 2 queries simultaneously?

Comment: How long does this query take? It's *very* unlikely that you're going to get much of a performance benefit from doing this as it requires starting multiple instances of MATLAB.

Comment: the query takes about 140s which is faster than the 173s if I run the 2 queries in a row. How would you suggest to do it then to get a better performance improvement?

Comment: You could also launch multiple matlab sessions explicitly via parcluster(). Example: c = parcluster(); job1 = createJob(c); task1 = createTask(job1, @myfunction, 0, {{1}, {2} }); submit(job1). You put your code in a myfunction which takes one input argument to play the role of i. However, this will probably not be any faster than parfor().